# How does pip determine a module's dependencies?

Tags: pip, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, pep517

This is likely an issue with my understanding of how python modules are packaged but I am confused as to how pip determines what a modules dependencies are when it installs a module. It appears that different build tools have their own way of specifying dependencies for example in poetry it is:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
requests = "^2.13.0"
```

Where as under setuptools it is:

```
[project]
dependencies = [
    "docutils",
    "BazSpam == 1.1",
]
```

So yer I'm confused as to how pip can determine what are a module's dependencies if each build system has its own unique specification within the `pyproject.toml` file. I'm guess theres some standard format in the built tar.gz file but if thats the case then how does pip know what to install if its installing from source like from a GitHub repo ?

Comment: In short... For obtaining the dependencies `pip` does not directly look at `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`, but it uses those to obtain the metadata. The metadata format, as well as the process necessary to generate this metadata out of a `setup.py` or a `pyproject.toml` file are standardized. Here is [some documentation about the metadata](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/). And the process to generate metadata is in [PEP 517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/) and [PEP 518](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the `setup.py` is the configure for `pip` to determine the dependency.

- For local packages, you should have `setup.py` in it.
- For github, the address also require a `setup.py` in that github repo.
- For poetry, although we explicitly define all dependency in `pyproject.toml`, the poetry will automatically generate a `setup.py` to the tar.gz after you input `poetry build`.

So, for any high level build tool, if we use `pip` to install the built out, the `pip` will all use `install_requires` settings in `setup.py`, no matter the `setup.py` generated explicitly or implicitly.

**Update:**

It looks the new pip version already could recognize the `pyproject.toml`, so in fact the `setup.py` auto generated is for low version pip compatibility use I think.

Comment: This makes sense thank you. As a followup question though, whats the interaction then between pip /  pyproject.toml / setup.py then?  Is this just another implicit generation of setup.py ?

Comment: @gowerc, `pyproject.toml` is designed to replace `setup.py` in most situations. But in the old time, `pip` did not recognize the format of `pyproject.toml`, so build system will generate a `setup.py` in the package. But I searched just now found: now pip already support `pyproject.toml`, so I think the `setup.py` in poetry built out tar.gz is not a must now.

Comment: interesting thanks for looking up and sharing